# C: SegFault Error when trying to free node

Tags: c, malloc, free, fault

```
void insert_queue (queue *this, queue_item_t item) {

   //Inserts a new item at the end of queue.
   queue_node *temp = malloc(sizeof (struct queue_node));
   temp->item = item;

   if (isempty_queue(this)) this->front = temp; 
   else this->rear->link = temp;
   this->rear = temp;
   free(temp);
}

queue_item_t remove_queue (queue *this) {
   assert (! isempty_queue (this));
   //This removes the first item from queue.
   queue_item_t temp = this->front->item;
   this->front = this->front->link;
   return temp;
}
```

I'm getting a seg fault error when I try to free 'temp'. I've tried doing some research and it suggests dereferencing temp. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT: When I remove free(temp), everything works fine, but I'm getting memory leaks. I'm not sure where to put free if it doesn't belong in this function. I also added my remove function. Should free go in here?

Comment: Where are you exactly getting the seg fault? Try to use printf and see till which point the program is running.

Comment: The `queue_node` which `temp` points to has become part of the queue data structure at the end of `insert_queue`. Do not free memory while it is still in use.

Comment: why are you freeing the very item you just put on you queue? And I have high confidence the fault is happening two lines prior, specifically at or around the code that does `this->rear->link = ...`, precisely because you did this once before. I bet your first item inserts "fine" (that being a term relative to not-actually-crashing).

Comment: When I remove free(temp), everything works fine, but I'm getting memory leaks. I'm not sure where to put free if it doesn't belong in this function.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling `free(temp)` in `insert_queue`? You just inserted some data in the queue. Calling `free` here does not make any sense, as it will make the data unavailable. It should be freed when you delete from queue.

Try removing that line. This won't cause memory leak.